# How to split my log file in multiple log files according to column values?

Tags: text-processing, sort, split

My connections log file is structured as follows:

> hostname direction timestamp bps

Here's a fragment of my log file:

```
www.youtube.com DOWNLOAD 1479897661131903 23508910
www.youtube.com UPLOAD 1479897661131922 735
fonts.gstatic.com DOWNLOAD 1479897660289990 527
ssl.gstatic.com UPLOAD 1479897660152435 2094
fonts.gstatic.com DOWNLOAD 1479897660290973 6662177
```

I want to sort it according both timestamp and hostname: I tried

`sort -k 3 -o sortedTimestamps.log connectionLog.txt`

and the result is

```
ssl.gstatic.com UPLOAD     1479897660152435 2094
fonts.gstatic.com DOWNLOAD 1479897660289990 527
fonts.gstatic.com DOWNLOAD 1479897660290973 6662177
www.youtube.com DOWNLOAD   1479897661131903 23508910
www.youtube.com UPLOAD     1479897661131922 735
```

Now, this is just a sample: there are more and more rows, and for now, with the `sort` above, the log file is just sorted by timestamp. Since I need to plot this, I'd like to have different log files according to `hostname` and `direction`, containing `timestamp` and `bps`.

The final result would be having one log file for each `hostname`:

`www.youtube.com_DOWNLOAD_log`,

`www.youtube.com_UPLOAD_log`,

`fonts.gstatic.com_DOWNLOAD_log`,

`fonts.gstatic.com_UPLOAD_log`

and so on; each log file should contain just two columns, sorted `timestamp` and its corresponding `bps`.

E.g.: `www.youtube.com_DOWNLOAD_log` contains:

```
timestamp1 bps1
timestamp2 bps2
timestamp3 bps3
...
```

Plotting this on a graph, X-axis would be `timestamp`, and Y-axis `bps`. I will plot them all together and see how `bps` changes in time for various connections.

P.S.: this is my first attempt to visualize data, so there may be a smarter way to plot a log file structured like mine, but since here questions should be answered and not discussed, please help me splitting my log file in multiple log files, one for each hostname-direction.

**Edit(2)**: thanks to Kalavan, here's my script:

Oh, the pipe! Oh, the power of Bash! I love it! Here's my full script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\nCleaning previous log files...\n"
rm *.log

# File name: HOSTNAME_DIRECTION.log

sort -k1 -k3n connectionLog.txt | awk '{print $3 " " $8 >> $1"_"$2".log"}'

to_plot_upload_files="plot "
to_plot_download_files=" plot "

for file in $(ls *UPLOAD.log); do
    to_plot_upload_files="$to_plot_upload_files \"$file\" using 1:2 with lines, "
done

for file in $(ls *DOWNLOAD.log); do
    to_plot_download_files="$to_plot_download_files \"$file\" using 1:2 with lines, "
done

echo $to_plot_upload_files | gnuplot -persist
echo $to_plot_download_files | gnuplot -persist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters try something like this. You could tweak it further if it suits you:

```
sort -k1 -k3n connectionLog.txt | awk '{print $1 " " $3 " " $4 >> $1".log"}'
```

**Edit:**

I missed that you don't want hostnames in logs. Omit printing first field ($1).

Comment: Thank you, at least I have a basis to work on! I'll share the script when I'll make it work.

Comment: By the way, what else do you need it to do?

Comment: Don't worry I'll do it by myself, I just needed some basic concepts (sort by multiple `k`, pipe, `awk`) to begin with.